# Error when using a select (MUI) to render the appropriate element

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I am a bit stuck in a little "learning" project, I am working on.

To Preface, I am using React with Typescript.

I am trying to use a select element, to choose an option that will render the appropriate element just below.

```html
function ItemConfig() {

    const [item, setItem] = useState<ItemType | undefined>(undefined)

    const ItemSelect = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        var item = ItemTypes.find(s => s.value = event.target.value)
        if(item != null)
        {
            console.log(item.label);
            setItem(item);
        }
    }


  return (
    <Container>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControl sx={{
                marginBottom: 1
            }}>
                <InputLabel variant='standard' htmlFor="itemType">
                Item Type</InputLabel>
                <Select 
                label="itemType"
                onChange={ItemSelect}
                value={"0"}
                >
                    {ItemTypes.map((item, index) => (
                        <MenuItem value={item.value} key={index}>{item.label}</MenuItem>
                    ))}

                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <Box>
                {item?.element}
            </Box>
            
        </FormGroup>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ItemConfig
```

I have also created a "type" for the objects.

```js
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export type ItemType = {
  element: ReactNode,
  label: string,
  value: string,
};
```

and an array of items of that type

```js
const ItemTypes: ItemType[] = [
        {
            label: "Type 0",
            value: "0",
            element: <Type0/>
        },
        {
            label: "Type 1",
            value: "1",
            element: <Type1/>
        },
        {
            label: "Type 2",
            value: "2",
            element: <Type2/>
        },
        {
            label: "Type 3",
            value: "3",
            element: <Type3/>
        },
        
    ]

    export default ItemTypes;
```

Now the problem, is that when I select an item, The first Item in the List changes to whatever I first selected, and I then get a message in the console stating I have an invalid value.

something like this

> act_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `0` for the select component.
> Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are `3`, `1`, `2`, `3`.

The rendered element is always Item[0] as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, note the code provided was copied over and changed for brevity so there could be a spelling mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well "foot in mouth" moment, all because of jumping around "languages"

In my handler I had,

```
var item = ItemTypes.find(s => s.value = event.target.value)
```

when it should have been

```
var item = ItemTypes.find(s => s.value === event.target.value)
```